# Foreign key to another app in Custom User

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have a problem when a CustomUser is used.

apps.accounts.MyUser defines a relathionship (ForeignKey) to
apps.registro.models.InstitucionEducativa. But, when runserver is executed, it shows me the following error :

`apps.accounts.MyUser.school: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'apps.registro.models.InstitucionEducativa', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`

My settings.INSTALLED_APPS is equal to :

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI,
    PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'apps.registro',
    'apps.accounts',
    'apps.pages',
    'apps.core',
    'apps.conf',
    'apps.utils',
    'apps.generic',
    'apps.service',
    'apps.resource',
    'apps.friends',
    'apps.forums',
    'apps.links',
    # 'oauth2_provider',
    # 'rest_framework',
 )

THIRD_APPS = (
    'django_extensions',
    'import_export',
    'social.apps.django_app.default'
),
```

Could somebody give me a hand with this? . Thanks!

Comment: apps.accounts.models.MyUser or apps.accounts.MyUser ... the error is definitive..

Comment: plz, add code of 2 models which defines relation